# Using SimpleSAMLphp in symfony with composer

Tags: symfony, vendor, simplesamlphp

I would like to implement the SimpleSamlPHP bundle in my symfony project But, I'm having some issues with the redirect after the login.

Let me explain a little:

I have loaded "simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp" in my composer. So, the bundle sits in the vendor directory.

Then I wrote my own bundle where I configured the simplesaml, made controllers with login actions,...

Everything works (in the sense that I effectively have a button that redirects to the Idp (I configured) and does its thing). But then I get redirected to: *http://BASEURL/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/IDENTIFIER*, which it does not find, because the files are in the vendor bundle.

When reading the documentation carefully, I saw that the baseUrl should point to the simplesaml package. But, because that package is in the vendor, I can't do that.

Is there a way to still use the simpleSAMLphp bundle or do I need to look for a symfony bundle to use simpleSAML?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get the best answers, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I had similar issues, and just to not bother with it (why mix and prix two different systems, I soft linked from the public direcory of my FW to the www folder of the simplesaml, and from then on, two separate systems live happily together.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to give a try to :
https://www.lightsaml.com

I've tried to do a simple IDP / SP service and it works pretty well and straightforward. Along that I find the website examples also well written so you can start with a base.

If still want to use simplesaml search for "simplesamlphp-bundle" in packagist.org there is at least 3 packages that bundlify this and can help you out to set it up.

Comment: lightsaml seems to be outdated andstale meanwhile and is designed for Symfony 2. Ist there any solution suitable for symfony 4/5 ?

Comment: It's open source so you can just fork it and adapt it so the rest of the community benefits from it too. Web devs are mainly too lazy and need everything last version to cope with their framework (Speaking mainly for myself here). That's sadly not the case for every package. But try out doing a deep search, maybe there is something... Good luck!

Comment: Forget about Lightsaml, it's dead. Install SimpleSAMLphp via composer, configure it as per documentation and then refer to https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/simplesamlphp-sp, item 6